# How to properly convert SHA1CryptoServiceProvider to c++?

Tags: c++, qt

I need to convert this C# code into QT C++:

```
 SHA1 sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
 byte[] resultSha1 = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(PASS));
 PASS = (BitConverter.ToString(resultSha1).Replace("-", string.Empty)).ToLower();
```

I tried using this but the output is nowhere near the desired one:

```
 sha1 = new QCryptographicHash(QCryptographicHash::Sha1);
 resultSha1 = sha1->hash(userPASS.toUtf8(), QCryptographicHash::Sha1);

 userPASS = QString(resultSha1).replace("-", "");
```

What do you suggest on properly doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to try:

1. Check if `Encoding.Default` is actually UTF-8.
2. Check if the inputs are the same
3. `QCryptographicHash#hash` produces its digest in binary instead of hex, so you need to do `resultSha1.toHex()` first.

   ```
   userPASS = QString("%1").arg(QString((QCryptographicHash::hash(userPASS.toUtf8(),QCryptographicHash::Sha1).toHex())));
   ```